# Bottom right backgrounds under scrollbar

Tags: css, background, scrollbar

I'm planning on using a little image in the corner of my divs as a resizing controller.
I have an example of my problem :

```
#scroll {
  height : 200px;
  width : 200px;
  border : red 1px solid;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAsklEQVR4nNWQTYqEMBQG+77+8VD0LoaEkCDifTQa9S7VW6GdUadXs3iLWtRH8V7A65v7Sv7nA03T8OeBuq4ZhoF935/LVVXR9z3btj0vKMuSrutY15XHPxARvPfEGPHeIyL3C0QE5xwxRpxzHPlSLooCay3LsmCt5ciXBXmeY4xhnmeMMRz58gdZlqG1JoSA1poz/nEgTVOUUoQQUErxG3/ISZLQti3TNHGHTwvGceQuvwGzOfZWmm6CFQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) bottom right no-repeat; 
}
```

without scrollbar : https://jsfiddle.net/s78zkbj2/8/

with scrollbar : http://jsfiddle.net/s78zkbj2/9/

As you can see, image that i used on background, attached to the bottom-right of the div, is overlapped by a scrollbar.

Is it possible to move background image to a visible area of div (left from scrollbar ) by CSS when scrollbar is shown?

Comment: You could use textarea. why do you need image and what is the purpose of using br

Comment: @GopsAB: why `textarea`?

Comment: it just looks like text area. By default there is a maximize option

Comment: @GopsAB as far as i know, resize of textarea doesn't work in ie8,9 and firefox. Plus, there is this bug in Chrome : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94583

Comment: So you need a structure which is maximizable by only css and you need i.e 8 support. then i hope the answer is no only with CSS

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, It is impossible to maximize an image without javascript or jquery `only by using css with your current design`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to position a background image, but if I were you I'd do something different.
Don't use a background! Just put  a p tag inside your div and the image you want inside that p tag. Position your div as relative and the p as absolute.
Use properties bottom and right to make adjustments to the px
like this:

CSS

```
#scroll {
position:relative;
height : 200px;
width : 200px;
border : red 1px solid;
overflow : auto;
}


p#resizer {
position:absolute; 
width:24px;
height:20px; 
bottom: 0;
right: 8px; 
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="scroll">

1
<br>
        1
<br>    1
<br>    1
<br>    1
<br>
        1
<br>    1
<br>    1
<br>    1
<br>    1
<br>    1
<br>    1
<br>
        1
<br>
    <p id="resizer">
        img
    </p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s78zkbj2/10/

Comment: thank you for a response! Maybe I am asking too much, but I want to avoid modifications of DOM - there is some piece of code that get html content of div and use it as value for some business logic. Of course, it is possible to filter out that particular element, but is it inconvenient? :)